# Error playing Video in Android Application

Tags: android, video

I am trying to play a MP4 inside my android app but for some reason it doesn't work.

I have seen all the formats and file containters for android on :
https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Is there an online or offline converter I can use to make this video work?

My Main :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LinearLayout screen;
Handler handler;
int fadeTime;
Button BtnTextColor;
Random rnd = new Random();
Button BackgroundButton;
final Context context = this;
private Button button;
private EditText result;
Button ChangeName;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




            VideoView mediaPlayer = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
            String uriPath2 = "android.resource://com.example.toyo.playvideo/"+R.raw.video;
            Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(uriPath2);
            mediaPlayer.setVideoURI(uri2);
            mediaPlayer.requestFocus();
            mediaPlayer.start();

fadeTime = -20; //text fade timer

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar theactionbar = getSupportActionBar(); //ActionBar
    screen = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.screen); //Background Screen


    //hide action bar (top)
    theactionbar.hide();


    //fades from white to blue

    ObjectAnimator colorFade = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(screen, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(), Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0), 0xff7F87CF);
    colorFade.setDuration(3000);
    colorFade.start();

    //fade text

    Animation animFadeIn;
    animFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.text_fade);
    animFadeIn.start();
    animFadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animFadeIn.setDuration(8000);
    animFadeIn.start();


    DelayedDialog();


    // Button Listeners
    BackgroundButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Change_Background);
    ChangeName = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ChangeWelcome);


    ChangeName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //Enter Name
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        Dialog();

                }
            });


}

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

    // R. Button checked
    final boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();


    // Which R. Button was checked
    switch (view.getId()) {
        //Rapid R.Button selected
        case R.id.BackgroundRapidChange:
            if (checked) {

                BackgroundButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    //Rapid Background Switch


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        RapidBackgroundColor();

                        BtnTextColor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Change_Text);
                        final TextView tt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Welcome_Text);

                        //Rapid Text Switch
                        BtnTextColor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                RapidTextColor();

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                if(checked == false) {
                Dialog();
                }
            }



            break;

        //Slow R. Button selected
        case R.id.BackgroundSlowChange:
            if (checked) {

                //Slow Background Switch
                BackgroundButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        SlowBackgroundChangeColor();


                        BtnTextColor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Change_Text);

                        //Slow Text Switch
                        BtnTextColor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                SlowTextColor();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });


            }

            break;
    }


}


public void SlowBackgroundChangeColor() {

    int Changecolor = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    ObjectAnimator ChangecolorFade = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(screen, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(),
            Color.argb(Changecolor, Changecolor, Changecolor, Changecolor), Changecolor);


    //slow change
    ChangecolorFade.setDuration(2000);
    ChangecolorFade.start();

}

public void SlowTextColor() {
    final TextView tt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Welcome_Text);
    int Changecolor = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    int ChangecolorText = Color.argb(225, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));


    ValueAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(tt, "textColor", ChangecolorText, Changecolor);
    colorAnim.setDuration(2000);
    colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());

}

public void RapidTextColor() {
    final TextView tt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Welcome_Text);
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    tt.setTextColor(color);
}

public void RapidBackgroundColor() {
    int Changecolor = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    ObjectAnimator ChangecolorFade = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(screen, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(),
            Color.argb(Changecolor, Changecolor, Changecolor, Changecolor), Changecolor);

    //fast change
    screen.setBackgroundColor(Changecolor);

}
public void Dialog(){
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPrompt);
result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextResult);

LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        context);

final AlertDialog.Builder noText = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        context);

alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
        .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

alertDialogBuilder
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                            if(userInput.getText().length() ==0){
                                Dialog();
                            }

                        TextView ChangeWelcomeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Welcome_Text);
                                ChangeWelcomeText.setText("Welcome \n"  + userInput.getText());
                    }
                });

AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
}

public void DelayedDialog() {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Dialog();

        }
    }, 4000);
}
}
```

And this is my Layout xml :

```
<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/backgroundoption"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/BackgroundRapidChange"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:text="Rapid" />

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/BackgroundSlowChange"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:text="Slow" />

</RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/Auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:text="Auto" />

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/Manual"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:text="Manual" />
</RadioGroup>




<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change Background"
    android:id="@+id/Change_Background"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    >
</Button>

<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change Text"
    android:id="@+id/Change_Text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    >
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ChangeWelcome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change Name"
    >

</Button>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Welcome_Text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="80dp"
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >


</TextView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonPrompt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Please Enter your Name" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextResult"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</EditText>


<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

It is a bit long and quite messy, it's my first Android App

Comment: What do you mean by "will never play"? Any error messages in the logcat?

Comment: the error I'm getting is



    `07-09 04:22:12.590 12805-12805/geepool.myfirstandroidapp     E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set`

Comment: The code I am using is :

                `VideoView mVideoView2 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        String uriPath2 = "android.resource://com.example.toyo.playvideo/"+R.raw.video;
        Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(uriPath2);
        mVideoView2.setVideoURI(uri2);
        mVideoView2.requestFocus();
        mVideoView2.start();`

Comment: Can you post the entire code of your activity and your layout?

Comment: I uploaded it to 

http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/7403

Comment: And here is my main activity http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/7404

Comment: It's better if you can paste your code here in your question body.

Comment: "Should have subtitle controller already set", I get this error message even if the video is working properly, provide us with your code please

Comment: Just added it to the question body :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, From what i managed to notice the following line caused the issue;

```
 String uriPath2 = "android.resource://com.example.toyo.playvideo/"+R.raw.video;
```

The R file gives a human readable values for android resources which is mainly a kind of a translation of Ids/numbers given by android system to these resources

The line was read like the following;

> android.resource://com.example.toyo.playvideo/2131427330

concatenating a number not the video file name to the url, besides you can either read the file from internal resources by R.raw.fileName, or use the online URL of it

another note;

```
<VideoView
       android:id="@+id/videoView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

use the following instead of the previous;

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

give the video container fixed width/height or minimum width/height as videos take a bit to load and you might get confused if it's working or not if the size was large and took it too long to load

Good luck, wish my answer was helpful

Comment: Thank you :D it worked but most importantly I learnt something new :D
Thank you once again, your help is very much appreciated